# Как получить registration_ids из device group?

Tags: firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing_device_groups
В документации для менеджмента устройствами предлагается использовать device group. Можно ли через API получить список устройств находящихся в группе, учитывая что имеется админский доступ к firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google такую возможность не предоставляет, и предлагает организовать такую логику на своей стороне.
Т.е сохраняем id устройств и id групп, организуем связь между устройствами и группами